# Сохранение 2 models в 1 view

Tags: yii2

У меня есть примерно следующая структура backend'а.

Но она не работает, прошу помощи что мне необходимо сделать чтоб оно заработало.

(Необходимо сделать чтоб я мог с 1 actovform заполнять сразу 2 таблицы - клиенты и телефон - соответственно в разные таблицы).

**model - Клиенты:**

```
model - Клиенты

return 'client_client';
}
public $ClientClient;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['age', 'client_id'], 'integer'],
        [['first_name', 'patronymic', 'last_name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'first_name' => 'First Name',
        'patronymic' => 'Patronymic',
        'last_name' => 'Last Name',
        'age' => 'Age',
        'client_id' => 'Client Id',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getClient_id()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ClientPhone::className(), ['client_id' => 'id']);
}
public function getNumber()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ClientPhone::className(), ['phone_digital' => 'id']);
}
```

**model - Телефон:**

```
class ClientPhone extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'client_phone';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['client_id'], 'integer'],
        [['phone_digital'], 'required'],
        [['phone_digital'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['client_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => ClientClient::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['client_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'client_id' => 'Client ID',
        'phone_digital' => 'Phone Digital',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getClient()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ClientClient::className(), ['id' => 'client_id']);
}
    public function getClientNumber()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ClientClient::className(), ['id' => 'phone_digital']);
}
}
```

**controller:**

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Clientclient();
    $phone = new ClientPhone();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $phone->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model::validateMultiple([$model, $phone])) {

        $model->save(false);
        $phone->client_id = $model->id;
        $phone->phone_digital = $model->phone_digital;
        $phone->save(false);


        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'phone' => $phone,
            // 'ClientClient' => $ClientClient,
        ]);
    }

}
```

**Ну и _form (создано с помощью Gii)**:

```
<div class="clientclient-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'patronymic')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($phone, 'phone_digital')->widget( MaskedInput::class, ['mask' => '9999999999'])?>

<?= $form->field($phone, 'client_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'age')->textInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: а для чего это? `$phone->phone_digital = $model->phone_digital;` по всей видимости у Clientclient нет аттрибута phone_digital

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, поможет в таком случае метод [link()](https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-db-active-record.html#saving-relations).
Сначала необходимо сохранить основную модель, а затем применить указанный метод.

```
$model->save();
$phone->link('client', $model);
```

Также стоит отказаться от использования `ClientClient::className()`, вместо этого используйте `ClientClient::class`